# Direct Mapping of 8GByte memory with 64-bit addressable word size

Tags: memory, computer-architecture, cache

The question: A computer has 8 GByte of memory with 64-bit addressable word sizes. Each block of memory stores 16 words. The computer has a direct-mapping cache of 128 blocks

Calculate the tag bits, Line number bits, and offset bit.
To solve the question, here is what I did.
8GB = 1GW (64 bit word = 8 bytes/word), which requires 30 bits (log 2 1G = 30). The memory address is divided into line number and word number. With 16 words per line, we need 4 bits for the block offset. Next, since block stores 16 words, there must be 16 lines in cache to store 128 blocks so line number bits 4 (log 2 16 = 4) and then or tag bits 30 - 4 - 4 = 22 bits for tag bits.

Please tell me if this is correct or not? If not, provide solution.

On an unrelated note, to get Tag bits is this formula valid, log 2 (main memory size / cache size).

Comment: I think it helpful to recapitulate, in the question, the relation of "Line" and "block".